# Multiple ember js apps?

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently adding ember.js to an existing rails app. Is it common to serve different ember apps based on route if the functionality is substantially different? Or is it better to keep it as one ember app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that Ember intends you to use it is that you have one Ember application, and all the back-end stuff such as database interactions are handled by Ruby. Ember just communicates with the back-end to get what it needs.

However, if you feel comfortable having separate Ember applications on different pages, then that's absolutely fine, but it's not how Ember would **like** you to use it, since it's an *ambitious* framework.